# Historical names used for variables, e.g. y=f(x). Why not z=f(y)?

Tags: notation, math-history

The traditional rule for quantity symbols in math is to use first letters of Latin alphabet for constants, and last letters for variables.

I just wonder why the two most used variable symbols, $x$ and $y$, are not $y$ and $z$. For example, why don't we see more often: $y=f(z)$ or $z=f(y)$. It seems Greeks had also zeta in their alphabet, which was borrowed by Romans.

---

I searched in [A History of Mathematical Notations](https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp/page/n9/mode/2up), a book referenced in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70396/874001), but I wasn't able to locate relevant explanations due to the mass of information it contains. However in [history of Z letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z#Latin), I saw Z was removed for some centuries, perhaps upon request of Roman censor Appius Claudius. Could that be the reason for not using $z$?

Comment: This may be more relevant on the "History of Science and Mathematics" stack exchange site

Comment: @Sambo, you may be right, though there are also a lot of [history questions here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history). Whatever I'm ok for mods to move the question.

Comment: For centuries Latin was the universal scholarly language in Europe (until the beginning of 19th century). For eaxmple, Euler and Gauß published in Latin. So your conjecture could be true. But I am not an expert.

Comment: We can guess... but as with many things in history there is not much way for us to know for sure and there may have been multiple separate reasons for something to be the way it is.  [One theory](https://www.ted.com/talks/terry_moore_why_is_x_the_unknown?language=en) has to do with our translating out of Arabic, we chose to use a $\chi$ (*chi*) as a placeholder for the arabic sheen(?) بعض, and the $\chi$ was later represented by an $x$.

Comment: [Another theory](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/variables/) is that Descartes popularized the usage of early letters for constants and later letters for variables.  Although he didn't personally have much preference between which to use at the time, when printing presses got involved, since $y$'s and $z$'s were used more often in other words in the French language there were more $x$'s available than the others and so out of necessity this became the preferred letter for unknown variables.  This trend eventually gave way to the conventions we have today.

Comment: See [Why are $x$ and $y$ commonly used as mathematical placeholders?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/why-are-x-and-y-commonly-used-as-mathematical-placeholders)